# register_activation_hook doesn't fire at all

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions

The following is my code. I'm new to plugin development. I honestly feel like I've looked everywhere there is to look for a solution. More than likely it's something stupid, but I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what's wrong with this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<?php
global $timesheetPluginInit;
$timesheetPluginInit = new TimesheetPluginInit();

class TimesheetPluginInit {

    //Calls all init functions
    function timesheet_init_plugin() {
        $this->timesheet_create_dbs();
        $this->timesheet_create_roles();
        $this->timesheet_admin_bar_removal();
        $this->timesheet_add_plugin_caps();
    }

    //create database tables
    function timesheet_create_dbs() {
        //....
    }

    //creates roles
    function timesheet_create_roles(){
        //...
    }

    //kills admin bar
    function timesheet_admin_bar_removal(){
        //...
    }

    //adds admin plugin capabilities
    function timesheet_add_plugin_caps(){
         //...
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'TimesheetPluginInit', 'timesheet_init_plugin' ) );
```

For the full code, here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/broskees/69590f9d0baa670bd71b4fb4f6c8b2ba

Answer (score 0):

The [`register_activation_hook`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) as the first parameter takes:

> $file
>   (string) (required) Path to the main plugin file inside the wp-content/plugins directory. A full path will work.

So using `__FILE__` for the tag works only when you do it in the main plugin file i.e. `plugins/my-super-plugin/my-super-plugin.php`.